# How i can make conditionals in this template string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

Nowadays i have this object:

```
const messages = {
  required: field => `${field} needs to be filled!`,
}
```

That print me:

```
nome needs to be filled
```

I'm trying to make a condition in this template string to change the value of the field based in a condition. I tried something like:

```
const messages = {
  required: field => `
   ${field => {
    if(field === 'nome') {
     'name'
    }
    if(field === 'endereco') {
     'address'
    }
   }} needs to be filled!
  `,
}
```

But when i print the message i'm receiving:

> field => { if(field === 'nome') { return 'name' } } needs to be
>   filled!

And i need:

```
name needs to be filled
```

Comment: Why not move the conditional outside the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make it too complicated

```js
const field = "nome";
const messages = {
  required: `${field === 'nome'?'name': field} needs to be filled!`
}
console.log(messages.required)

const messages1 = {
  required: field => `${field === 'nome' ? 'name' : field} needs to be filled!`
}
console.log(messages1.required("nome"))
```

Comment: works well, but i can have more than one field to compare, so i can't use ternary condition in this case

Comment: @veroneseComS That is not clear from your question. You can add as many conditions to the ternary as you wish

Comment: @mplugjan sorry, i updated my question with more details

Comment: i can have something like:   required: field => `${field === 'código'?'code': field || field === 'endereco'?'address' : field} needs to be filled!` ?

Comment: You can have a lookup table but I’m away from keyboard

Comment: i think i get what i need with: string: field => `${field === 'code'?'Código' : field === 'description'?'Nome do livro' : field === 'authors'?'Autores' : field } está com o tipo incorreto! (esperado texto)` i'm still testing it but i think it's that i need

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can only have expressions inside of template literals, not statements (which is what you are trying to do, using an `if` is a statement). You can use a ternary to create an expression:

```js
const messages = {
  required: field => `${field === 'nome' ? 'name' : field} needs to be filled!`,
};
```

If you have more than one conditional, then you'll have to break your conditionals out, and flesh out the arrow function a little more:

```js
const messages = {
  required: field => {
    let display;

    if (field === 'nome') {
      display = 'name';
    } else if (field === 'other condition) {
      display = 'other thing';
    } else {
      display = field;
    }

    return `${display} needs to be filled`;
  },
};
```

Comment: I can have more than one condition to make, so i can't use if ternary

Answer (score 1):

```js
const messages = {
  required: field => `${field === "nome" ? "name" : field} needs to be filled!`,
}
```

Inside the template literals you can't do multiple line expressions, like functions, but you can use ternary operator.